# the regular expression in expect

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I have a question about the following code in TCL/EXPECT:

```
expect { 
    timeout { 
        puts "timeout error"
    }
    -re "Please enter the play name" {
        exp_send $common1
        exp_continue
    }
    -re "Please enter the play name_type" {
        exp_send $common2
        exp_continue
    }
    -re "Now you can get the information of the play" {
        expect {
        -re "\r"
            }
    }
    }
```

if I run the code above, it will be stuck at the second code block(-re "Please enter the play name_type"). why this will happen? and if I move the second code block(-re "Please enter the play name_type") on the top, the first two will pass. what is the reason?

And seems like the third code block is never executed, I added some trace inside of it like this: `puts "executed!!!!"` , the message never shows, and seems like it ignored the third code block and executed the code under the whole expect block, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first pattern is a substring of the second pattern, the first pattern will match twice. When using `expect -re` it is commonly suggested to match up to the end of a line, so

```
expect { 
    timeout { 
        puts "timeout error"
    }
    -re "Please enter the play name: $" {
        exp_send $common1
        exp_continue
    }
    -re "Please enter the play name_type: $" {
        exp_send $common2
        exp_continue
    }
    -re "Now you can get the information of the play.*\r" 
}
# continue processing here
```

I'm making as assumption that the question ends with colon, space and end of line. Adjust accordingly.

My usual expect advice: when you're debugging or developing your program, add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script.

Comment: thank you, but why the first pattern will match twice？in my code, the  first block -re "Please enter the play name", so the code is stuck here, and waiting the output trigged by the expect_send $common1, and if it matches, it exit the first block,and continue the second block stuck at -re "Please enter the play name_type", and waiting for the output trigged by the expect_send $common2, why the he first pattern will match twice? and why the third pattern is not executed and be ignored?

Comment: @ratzip Expect matches things one character at a time; it doesn't know that there is more to come at the point when the first pattern matches. The fix is to force the pattern to only match when it is _unambiguously_ one thing or another. It makes your code clearer too, a double bonus.

Comment: @DonalFellows I do not understand, there are three patterns there, it will try to match there patterns simultaneously, the first output in the screen is "Please enter the play name", the first pattern matches, so it send the common1, then the second output is "Please enter the play name_type", it should match the second pattern,right? you mean it should match the first pattern? why?